# Create Uri for MediaStore.createTrashRequest function

Tags: java, android

The android [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore#createTrashRequest(android.content.ContentResolver,%20java.util.Collection%3Candroid.net.Uri%3E,%20boolean)) says that the MediaStore `createTrashRequest` function requires a List of Uris as parameter. When I performed a search, I can see that there are two different kinds of Uri: DocumentUri and MediaUri. But from the documentation, I couldn't figure out which kind of Uri is required as a parameter.

I tried passing the Uri returned from ACTION_PICK intent but it didn't work. The error is "`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: All requested items must be referenced by specific ID`"

Sample Uri: content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/1/content://media/external/images/media/30/ORIGINAL/NONE/image/jpeg/118418547

```html
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    ArrayList<Uri> imagesForDeletion = new ArrayList<Uri>();
    Uri imageURI = data.getData();
    imagesForDeletion.add(imageURI);

    List<Uri> urisToModify = imagesForDeletion;
    PendingIntent editPendingIntent = MediaStore.createTrashRequest(getContentResolver(), urisToModify,       true);

    try {
        // Launch a system prompt requesting user permission for the operation.
        startIntentSenderForResult(editPendingIntent.getIntentSender(), 101, null, 0, 0, 0);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It started working after creating a new URL using image ID: MediaStore.MediaColumns._ID

```html
ArrayList<Uri> imagesForDeletion = new ArrayList<Uri>();
Uri media_uri = data.getData();
String[] column = {MediaStore.Images.Media._ID};

Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(media_uri, column,
        null, null, null);
cursor.moveToFirst();
if(cursor.getCount()>0){
    int Media_ID = cursor.getInt(cursor
            .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns._ID));

    Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, Media_ID);
    imagesForDeletion.add(uri);

    List<Uri> urisToModify = imagesForDeletion;
    PendingIntent editPendingIntent = MediaStore.createTrashRequest(getContentResolver(), urisToModify, true);

    try {
        // Launch a system prompt requesting user permission for the operation.
        startIntentSenderForResult(editPendingIntent.getIntentSender(), 101, null, 0, 0, 0);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
cursor.close();
```

Comment: Not working with SD Card media, Have you tried that?